# apache internal dummy connection

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

i am doing some load testing on apache and i gets tons of internal dummy connections

```
::1 219 - [22/Dec/2011:11:02:57 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 181 "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 221 - [22/Dec/2011:11:02:58 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 181 "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 188 - [22/Dec/2011:11:02:59 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 181 "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 243 - [22/Dec/2011:11:03:03 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 181 "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 215 - [22/Dec/2011:11:03:04 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 181 "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
::1 178 - [22/Dec/2011:11:03:05 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 181 "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"
```

This is the virtual host config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal dummy connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ /blank.html [L]

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@email.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain/html
    ServerName domain
    ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/domain/error_log
    SetEnvIf REMOTE_ADDR "(.+)" CLIENTIP=$1
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^([0-9.]+)" CLIENTIP=$1
    LogFormat "%{CLIENTIP}e %D %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" trueip_combined
    CustomLog "/var/www/vhosts/domain/access_log" trueip_combined
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain/html>
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

To solve this i am readirecting all internal dummy connections to blank.html using the rewrite rule, but it give me a error in syntax?

```
[root@ip-10-56-1-98 ~]# /etc/init.d/httpd configtest
Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf:
RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the spaces like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
```

Comment: the syntax worked, but i still get the same errors on access log

Comment: What do you mean by "worked but get the same errors on access log"?

Comment: means it still logs the error "interal dummy error" and does not redirect to blank.html

Comment: You may consider simplifying that condition. I see no reason why you need to test for the full UA string here, and it's complicating things. Consider: RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Apache [NC] instead.

Comment: i have now put the rules in the virtualhost config and that works.. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Solution that works for me

Replace

```
CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
```

With

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "::1" loopback
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" loopback
CustomLog logs/access_log combined env=!loopback
```

[Source](https://www.thewebhelp.com/apache/internal-dummy-connection)